# How to find the remainder $x^y\bmod z$ quickly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I am searching for any rule to find the remainder  $x^y\bmod z$ where $x,y,z$ are positive integer.

Is there any rule to quickly find this remainder (without computing $x^y$)?

Comment: It only depends on the vales of $x,y$ and $z$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: You are more likely o get a useful answer if you give one or two concrete examples.

Comment: Is $x$ coprime to $z$?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem): $x^{\phi(z)} \equiv 1 \pmod z$ (assuming $x, z$ are coprime).

This means you can reduce $x^y \mod z = (x \mod z)^{y \mod \phi(z)}$.

Besides this, there's not much that can be said without knowing more about $x,y,z$.

Comment: Note the Euler's theorem requires $\:(x,z) = 1.\ \ $

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

As you ask about remainder, I guess we can assume that $x,y,z$ are positive integers. Then, what you are looking for is most probably the [Euler-Fermat theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Fermat_theorem), which states that
$$x^{\varphi(z)}\equiv 1 \pmod{z}$$
if $x$ is coprime to $z$.
Here $A\equiv B \pmod{z}$ means that $A$ and $B$ are *congruent* modulo $z$, i.e. they give the same remainder, that is, $z\,|\,A-B$. And, $\ \varphi(z)$ is the number of positive coprimes to $z$ which are less than $z$.

An important property of giving the same remainder is that it preserves addition and multiplication, in particular, if $x$ gives remainder $d$ modulo $z$, then $x\equiv d$ and we also have $x^y\equiv d^y\pmod{z}$.

Now, (supposing $x$ is coprime to $z$) you have to take the remainder of $y$ modulo $\varphi(z)$, say $y\equiv b\pmod{\varphi(z)}$, then we have
$$x^y\equiv d^y\equiv d^b \pmod{z} \,.$$
In case, $\gcd(x,z)\ne 1$, we might have to find the factors of $z$ and find the remainders w.r.t. these factors, and then use the Chinese remainder theorem to glue the remainders together to get something modulo $z$.